# mysql multiple WHERE from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to output a nice user table. But my query needs a WHERE from multiple tables.

At the moment... my query looks like:

```
$statsTable = "someTable";
$userTable = "someOtherTable";

$someData = "SELECT stats.* FROM $statsTable stats, $userTable user 
WHERE user.some_status = '0' 
AND (stats.some_value BETWEEN $rangeFrom AND $rangeTo) 
ORDER BY stats.some_value ASC 
LIMIT 0,10";

then mysqli_query and so on...
```

The output(array) has 2 times the data from $statsTable and the WHEREs are not working. I just want to select the $statsTable...

How to proceed?
Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is you've not described how stats table assocaites to the user table.  Describe the relationship between stats and user tables in your where clause or learn to use ANSI-92 joins as outlined in [this coding horror blog](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) or add keyword `Distinct` after `select`...  though I recommend against this last approach.  Understanding why you're getting the data is a better long term approach, and fixing your query... by adding and `statsTable.ssomefield = usertable.somefield`  Though using Ansi-92 joins would help prevent later

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the idea, don't solved my problem immediately, but nice to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$statsTable = "someTable";
$userTable  = "someOtherTable";

$someQueryForData = "SELECT stats.* 
                     FROM $statsTable stats
                     JOIN $userTable user
                     ON (user.id_stats = stats.id)
                     AND (user.some_status = '0')
                     WHERE (stats.some_value BETWEEN $rangeFrom AND $rangeTo) 
                     ORDER BY stats.some_value ASC LIMIT 0,10";
```

Edit: explaining you're basically need a join, building query's the way you are doing makes them not as readable and you can't really associate your tables.

Using joins after you made your "ON" statement you may just add an "AND"
And use that conjunction as a where which is way faster the using the where ITSELF

Comment: I agree, this works, however @Alexandre should explain why

Comment: Why did `AND (user.some_status = '0')` need to get moved to the join?  Looks like it could have been left in the where.  Same results, just wondering why.

Comment: Actually i think that would be better that way:

               `ON (user.id_stats = stats.id and user.some_status = '0')`
Its faster then putting into the where

Answer (score 0):

Just use a join.

Join the tables on a unique ID and then you will have the values from both tables.

[W3 Schools Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Should look like this

```
SELECT stats.* as stats, user.* as user
FROM statsTable
INNER JOIN userTable
ON stats.userId=user.userId
WHERE user.some_status = 0 AND (stats.some_value BETWEEN $rangeFrom AND     $rangeTo)
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: This will not work since you forgot the alias on both tables